# Pathfinding - Jump Point Search - open and closed lists

Tags: algorithm, path-finding, a-star

I wanted to make an efficient pathfinding algorithm so I got into jump point search. I read the publication about it as well as online material. It explains the process very well, however, I couldn't find material on how it should be merged with A*.
For example, I am not sure if the algorithm ever tries to add the same node to the open list multiple times, since the algorithm is supposed to eliminate same-length symmetric paths.
Should I do a check for that every time before I add a new node or should I add every jump point I find to the open list?

So in a nutshell, I would like to know how to handle the open and closed lists in a jump point search algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since JPS only works on 8-connected grid-graphs, and 8-connected grid graphs have a [consistent heuristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_heuristic) *(the [Chebyshev](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance) or [Euclidean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) distance, depending on your graph)*, you do not need to add any node to the OPEN list more than once.

Comment: My question is not whether i have to do it. In A*, you have to check if a node is already on the closed or open lists. If you don't, it Will add a node multiple times. I am asking if that can happen here.

Comment: @user2154375: You may have to add a node to the open list multiple times if you are using a non-consistent heuristic.  If you have a consistent heuristic, you will only have to add a node to the open list once ever.  This is true in both A\* and JPS.

Comment: Like I said, in A* you have to check if a node is in the list already. If it is, you don't add it, but calculate the alternative G value and switch parents to the last closed node if the new G value is lower than the previous. I am asking f this is necessary in jps. In other words, can the algorithm reach the same node from different locations? If it does, it could try to declare it a jump point multiple times, thus adding it to the open list multiple times, meaning the open/closed list check is necessary.

Comment: *"Like I said, in A\* you have to check if a node is in the list already [then] calculate the alternative G value and switch parents"* - And like I said, **that is not true if the heuristic you're using is consistent**.  It is **not** necessary in A\* to do that if you have a consistent heuristic.  It **is** necessary if you have a non-consistent heuristic.  JPS doesn't change that fact.  And since JPS only works on certain types of graphs, which I believe always have a consistent heuristic, **it will not be necessary to do that in JPS.**  I'm not sure how I can make this any more clear.

Comment: I learned A* over here http://www.policyalmanac.org/games/aStarTutorial.htm
the algorithm presented checks every time as i mentioned,
check "Summary of the A* Method"\2)\c)
How does one make the heuristic consistent?...

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i just noticed the link above describing consistent. The definition wasn't clear for me before. I think everything is in place now.